# C++ Iterator model versus Java Iterator model

Tags: java, c++, iterator

The basic iterator model of C++'s STL basically consists of a "give me the item at the current position" operator `*`, a "go to next item" operator `++` and an a predicate `==`/`!=` that is used to check (most of the time) against an end iterator. Of course, there are various further iterators with random access but the most basic one looks like described above.

In contrast, Java has `next()` and `hasNext()`. Next is roughly equivalent to using `++` and then `*`. `hasNext()` is something like comparison against end. Why has Java not adopted the C++ model (of course, it doesn't have operator overloading so it must mimic it by functions)? Especially, why was comparison against an end iterator dropped for a `hasNext()` method? I find it often harder to write iterators in Java than in C++ because the logic behind `next()` and `hasNext()` is often more complex than the one in the C++ operators.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347/iterators-in-c-stl-vs-java-is-there-a-conceptual-difference and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882855/what-is-the-difference-between-iterators-in-java-and-c

Comment: Different philosophies - Java was designed for simplicity, while STL iterators are patterned after C pointers.

Comment: @Scott Jones: I don't see the simplicity here...

Comment: @gexicide: what's simpler than `while (iter.hasNext()) { item = iter.next(); }` ?

Comment: Both C++ and Java have an extended for loop now that is even simpler.

Comment: @gexicide Definitely eye of the beholder.  I don't share a lot of Gosling's decisions (lack of unsigned support, generics, etc), but I do think iteration in Java (and similar languages) is less complex than mastering containers, iterators, and algorithms.

Comment: @gexicide: You can't remove elements with an enhanced `for` loop.

Comment: "Why has someone who isn't an SO user made a decision 10+ years ago" is not a good form of SO question.

Comment: Also, I'd guess that for linked lists, Java's iterators are probably easier to write than C++'s. More so for, say, trees, or potentially infinite lists. (But that's really a guess, I'm only barely aware of how C++ ones work.) Conceptually, it seems that Java's iterators are more abstracted, while C++'s are meant to make everything look like an array. This would also be the kind of "operator overloading abuse" that Gosling deliberately tried to avoid.

Comment: Java iterators also avoid having to pass a begin AND end to every function.

Comment: Now I'm really wondering how you'd make a C++ pre-order iterator for a binary tree. What's the beginning and the end object like? The Java implementation with chaining iterators for the subtrees would be mostly straightforward.

Comment: @millimoose: you could for example define iterators to contain a pointer to a node, and the end object to contain a null pointer. Then `operator*()` returns the value of the current node, and `operator++` tries to go left, and if there's no left child then it goes up the tree until it finds a right child, and if it can't find a right child either then sets itself to null. This would be a forward iterator -- if you want to go backwards too then I think you need more state in the iterator, although maybe not with cunning sentinal nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you must understand that C++ has pointers and an iterator simulates a pointer.

Java has no pointers everything is an object in Java

C++ interators are much more powerful.

See the duplicate answers from the above comments.

[Iterators in C++ (stl) vs Java, is there a conceptual difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347/iterators-in-c-stl-vs-java-is-there-a-conceptual-difference)

[What is the difference between iterators in Java and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882855/what-is-the-difference-between-iterators-in-java-and-c)

I'd suggest you read how are objects handled in Java - [Objects in Java](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=BF6HyZSN7EsC&pg=PA78&dq=java%20objects%20and%20references%20balloon%20-stackoverflow.com&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tISjUcecCuqM7Qak3oGAAw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=java%20objects%20and%20references%20balloon%20-stackoverflow.com&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should compare the C++ iterator with the Java [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html), which has indexed access.
Java's Iterator is for all kind of collections, and refrains from a possible inefficient indexed access with O(n) access. That is a choice. Of course one can iterate on a sublist, achieving a somewhat same result.

- In Java 7 the iterator already has second citizen status, as there is the `for (item : collection)`.
- In Java 8 `collection.forEach(function)` is provided.

The Java 8 `forEach` is a definite improvement: an Iterator from the outside maintains a state. `forEach` is done by the collection class itself. This has consequences for expressiveness (fluent combination), efficiency, concurrency and optimization. (Can be read elsewhere.)

Comment: I'm not sure how Java 8 is implemented, but I'd bet money on `forEach` ultimately using the Collection's `Iterator` anyway.

Comment: @millimoose mostly right; propaganda admitted, but then one could do something like `parallel().forEach(...)`. More importantly an Iterator needs an opened class. tree.forEach could simply be a visiting tree walk. _Did not look into it yet._

Answer (score 0):

forgive my english

1， java style iterator just like c++ forward iterator category, that a part of the c++ iterator

2， In c++， iterator just a part of STL， define a new iterator in c++ not just means you can traversal a data set, it also means you can use ability of the whole STL， that's very powerful；